# MySQL: Sort by constants paired with IDs

Tags: mysql

We have an Apache Solr instance that returns us IDs for a table, along with a score. The records look like this:

```
<doc>
    <int name="entity_id">13686</int>
    <float name="score">2.6653142</float></doc>
  <doc>
    <int name="entity_id">16506</int>
    <float name="score">2.5128825</float></doc>
<doc>
```

We have an already existing SQL query (that's part of a larger ORM framework). We need to filter the collection on the `entity_id` part of the results. So far, we used a table for that, where we stored all the records we received from the Solr instance, then joined and sorted according to the attached `score`.

However, after some consideration we're at a point where the data stored in the table we join is so volatile, that it is only used for a single join, then dropped when a new search is executed (the Solr instance index can have changed in the mean time). So we would like to skip the table overhead altogether and somehow get the same functionality by using clever SQL.

For the `entity_id` that's pretty trivial with

```
entity_id IN (<list of entity_ids)
```

However, now we would need to generate a sort by the `score` part. Checking the documentation I can't see any way to do that by using `SORT BY` SQL.

Is there any way to sort a MySQL query by some constant list?

Comment: does it helps http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field ?

Comment: I think it might. Using FIELD (and it's counterpart ELT), I can generate a row of the scores that each entity_id has, then SORT BY it. So far, so imaginary. Will try now.

Comment: you can use something as `order by field(someothercol,'const1','const2'...);`

Comment: So, your suggestion worked like a charm. Post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Here comes the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [field()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) in conjunction with order by

```
order by field(someothercol,'const1','const2'...);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It's pretty fast, too, which I wouldn't have guessed (with about 250 entries).

Comment: yeah field() function is pretty nice and using with order by solves this kind of issue.